# x86 assembly, little endianness not being followed(or is it?) (Linux)

Tags: linux, assembly, endianness, x86

I am new to assembly language programming and I wrote a small program to print the integer using sys_write system call. Here's my code :

```
section .data

N: dw 216
chr: dw ,0,0,0,0x0a

section .bss

section .text

  global _start

_start:
            xor ax, ax
            mov ax, word [N]
            mov cx, 10 
            mov ebx,4

shift_while: div cx 
             add dx, 0x0030
             mov word [chr+ebx],dx
             sub ebx, 2 
             xor dx, dx
             cmp ax, 0
             jne shift_while
             call printchar

exit:        mov eax, 1
             mov ebx, 0
             int 80h


printchar:  pushad
            mov eax, 4
            mov ebx, 1
            mov ecx, chr
            mov edx, 8
            int 80h
            popad
            ret
```

I have hard coded 216, the number to be printed and I am getting the correct output. However what I am bemused by is the "mov word [chr+ebx],dx" instruction. dx contains 0x0032 in the first iteration so at the address [chr+ebx] this value should be stored as
32 00 (hex). But when I examined chr memory using gdb, it showed:

```
(gdb) x /5hx 0x80490d2
0x80490d2 <chr>:    0x0032  0x0031  0x0036  0x000a
```

what I expected was **0x3200 0x3100 0x3600 x0a00** and thought I'd have to do further memory manipulation to get the right result.
       Am I going wrong somewhere with this. Are there things I can't seem to see. I'd really appreciate a little help here. This is my first first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10):

It's just a representation thing - what you have in memory from a byte-wise perspective is

```
32 00 31 00 26 00 0a 00
```

but when you view this as 16 bit values it's

```
0032 0031 0026 000a
```

Similarly, if you viewed it as 32 bit values it would be:

```
00310032 000a0026
```

Such is the weirdness of little endianness. ;-)

Comment: Yep, little-endianess seems weird from the "viewing memory" aspect.  It makes somewhat more sense computationally.  I've been programming the 8086 since 1983:  it still takes some intentional initial concentration to make sense of what is displayed.

Comment: @BlackBear: yes, when we write numbers down we write them as big endian format, which is why big endian seems more natural and intuitive. For little endian you have to keep conceptually swapping the order of the bytes to map between multi-byte values and bytes in memory order.

Comment: @wallyk, @BlackBear et al: or you can look at memory right-to-left (with lowest memory address at the right). With that representation, everything maps again.

Comment: I link to think of RAM as top to bottom.  Makes it easier to map little and big endian.

Comment: @Brian: but then strings etc are back to front ?

Answer (score 4):

`gdb` is helping you out here.

You asked for the `h` (`halfword`) format, on a little-endian platform, so it is decoding the memory as 16-bit little endian-values for you.

If you use the `b` format instead, you'll see something more like you expected.

Comment: Yea I replaced the 'h' with the 'b' and got the right result, but it raised another doubt about how sys_write (`mov eax, 4... int 80h`) system call works. I am not aware of the exact implementation of sys_write so this might sound a bit silly. chr in memory is : `(gdb) x /8bx 0x80490d2
0x80490d2 <chr>: 0x32 **0x00** 0x31 **0x00** 0x36 **0x00** 0x0a   **0x00**`. I still got output on the console as 216**. What does sys_write do with the 0x00. If it were chr: db "Hello World", sys_write would have printed the string, reading each byte separately. Do keywords like db or dw decide it?

Comment: No, `db` and `dw` only decide how the assembler itself treats values. `sys_write` *is* writing this as 8 bytes -- here, to file descriptor 1 (standard output), which is connected to your console.  The 0x00 bytes are interpreted by the console terminal device driver as "do nothing" (ASCII "NUL") control characters.